# Why the text at the box not in the center?

Tags: titlesec, tcolorbox

Look at the code below:

```
 % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ,framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}
\tcbset{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\titleformat{\part}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\selectfont}
  {}{0pt}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[drop large lifted shadow=black,halign=center]
    \center{Part\hskip0.7em\thepart\newline#1}\end{tcolorbox}}[]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}[variant=american]%

\part{Simple}

\end{english}%
\tableofcontents{}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

What `Part I` is not at the center like `Simple`?

Thank you!

Comment: `\center` is not a command with an argument; remove it and also the related braces; `\newline` is known to not work as maybe expected in a `center` context. By the way, loading `mdframed` with two methods doesn't make much sense; since `tcolorbox` is much more powerful than `mdframed`, it's probably better to avoid `mdframed`.

Comment: @egreg, yes, but sometimes `mdframed` is much more simple... This is why I prefer to load it also :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use only

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[drop large lifted shadow=black,halign=center]
{Part~\thepart\\#1}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! BTW when you say "Use only" what do you mean? To do it only at `{ }` or to other thing? (Because I want to do with it more:) )

Comment: @heblyx, it means to use only that code inside `tcolorbox`. So, replace what is inside. The other part of your code has no relation with that.